# How to disable/enable a TextBox inside a UserControl from my WebForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I created a UserControl called "DadosFuncionario". Now, I'm using it in my WebForm. Sometimes, I need to enable or disable controls of my UserControl. It depends if I'm viewing or editing my record.

I tried to do it in two ways but no one of them is working.

Those are what I have tried:

```
1º

In my web form:

public partial class MyWebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private void EnableFields()
    {
         MyUserControl.EnableFields();
    }

    private void DisableFields()
    {
         MyUserControl.DisableFields();
    }

}

public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
     public void EnableFields()
     {
         txtName.Enabled = true;
     }

     public void DisableFields()
     {
         txtName.Enabled = false;
     }
}

2º
/***************************************/

In my Web Form

public partial class MyWebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private void EnableFields()
    {
         ((TextBox)MyUserControl.FindControl("txtName")).Enabled = true;
    }

    private void DisableFields()
    {
         ((TextBox)MyUserControl.FindControl("txtName")).Enabled = false;
    }
```

}

I thought that maybe my UpdatePanel was interfering but I added a trigger referencing my UserControle and anything happened.

Any idea about what to do to solve this issue?

Best Regards.

Comment: How are you registering the user control in your ASPX page? Do you use <%: Register for example? Is that how you're using it?

Comment: Is 2º the user control code?  Could you post the markup?  The UserControl is in the update panel, correct?

Comment: I'm registering in this way: <%@ Register Src="../Controls/DadosFuncionario.ascx" TagName="DadosFuncionario" TagPrefix="uc1" %>

Comment: "Brian Mains". The 2º code is in my Web Form and my UserControl is inside the UpdatePanel.